# Basic unit testing

Tags: verilog

I'm an experienced programmer but new to HDL. I'm trying to figure out how to implement basic unit testing for my hardware designs for a class I'm taking. I'm aware of SVUnit, but I need to submit the code so I would prefer to just implement the barebones testing functionality myself. This will also help me learn more.

I'm having trouble figuring out what language constructs to use. All I really need to do is instantiate a component, drive the inputs, then verify the output values. The verification is where I'm stuck. Does that need to go into an always block?

Even pointing me in the right direction for what terms I should be googling would be very helpful. So far I've tried: verilog modelsim unit testing, verilog modelsim self-checking testbench, etc without too much success.

EDIT: Example:
Let's say I have a design for a 1 bit half adder. How would I write a testbench to exercise every possible input combination, and automatically verify that the output is correct?

Comment: Without specific details about what data needs to be driven and how you expect t to know that it works, this question is to broad in scope for this forum,

Comment: Added a specific example

Comment: verilog+testbench+for+half+adder

Comment: All of the results drive the DUT, but none of them do automatic verification.

Comment: You do the verification the same way as the driver, except instead of driving the stimulus to the input pins, you compare the output pins to the expected result. For combinational logic, the expected reset is just a simple function of the stimulus.

Answer (score 0):

As a first draft I would look at something *like* this.

```
reg clk = 0;
reg rst_n;
initial
begin 
  rst_n = 'bx;
  #5
  rst_n = 1'b0;
  #20
  rst_n = 1'b1;
end

always @(clk)
begin
  clk = #10 ~clk;
end

reg a,b;
wire adder = a + b;
task test;
  input i0,i1,o;
  a = i0;
  b = i1;
  #1
  if (adder !== o)
     $display("Error:Incorrect output");
endtask
initial
begin
  wait(rst_n === 1'b0);
  @(posedge clk)
  test(0,0,0);
  @(posedge clk)
  test(0,1,1);
  @(posedge clk)
  test(1,1,0);
  @(posedge clk)
  test(1,0,1);
end
```

Then you might as a second draft implement test data as something like:

```
wire [3:0] stim_data [1:0];
wire [3:0] expected_output;
always @(posedge clk)
  if (!rst_n)
  begin
    cnt <= 2'b00;
  end
  else
  begin
    cnt <= cnt + 1;
  end
assign {a,b} = stim_data[cnt];
always @(posedge clk)
  if (!rst_n)
  begin
  end
  else
  begin
    if (adder !== expected_output[cnt])
      // add error message
  end
```

Hopefully that should get you started.